# CloudKit production databases wiped clean

Tags: ios, cloudkit

On our production app, the public database seems to have been reset. It looks like each user's private databases (~100K users) were reset as well. It looks to have happened this morning around 5AM GMT.

We did nothing on the CloudKit dashboard since December 2017.

Anyone seeing this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of support emails today from customers of my app reporting complete loss of data. It all seems to have happened in the last 24 hours. I'm actually glad to hear it wasn't my app.

Comment: Since this isn't really a good fit for SO, anyone seeing this should head to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103345

Comment: Good point to redirect @rmaddy